# override ip address or host label in Ansible play

Tags: ansible

On my personal network I have a simple list of hosts:

```
[host1]
192.168.1.2
[host2]
192.168.1.10
```

When I set up a local host, say 'host2', it has a random (dhcp) IP address. I've changed my hosts.ini and overriden the host IP address, then I use host vars to actually set the IP address I want into its dhcpcd.conf.

My play has all of my local machines, so I need the host label to match. But I can't get this to work on the first boot without some manual work.

I can think of a few workarounds:

1. override the IP in a manual inventory on the `ansible-playbook` commandline
2. specify a host ip and hostname in a manual inventory on the `ansible-playbook` commandline
3. set a ansible host name on the `ansible-playbook` commandline

The problem is I can't get any of them to work:

```
ansible-playbook play.yml -i "[host2]\n192.168.0.123," --limit host2
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: host2

ansible-playbook play.yml -i "192.168.0.123 ansible_host=host2," --limit host2
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: host2

ansible-playbook play.yml -i "192.168.0.123," -e "ansible_host=host2" --limit host2
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: host2
```

I really think the third idea has merit, I just can't get there from here. Since this is a oneshot type of problem I don't want to have to create a temporary hosts file, but I'm unsure of another way to do it.

Note having an earlier play/task that calls `add_hosts` **almost** works, but given host2 already exists in inventory, I either have to null out my inventory or (somehow) call my host exclusively. Remember, this is for bootstrapping, so the idea is to avoid any magic later.

Apologies for this being kinda long. I wanted to give context for the XY problem and also ask my specific strategy/problem.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using a dynamic inventory based on the mac address of your devices?

Just a small example. Of course it needs to be improved but it is for your reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,
                        unicode_literals)

import json
import socket
import subprocess
import re


def main():
    print(json.dumps(inventory(), sort_keys=True, indent=2))


def inventory():
    ip_address = find_ip()

    return {
        'all': {
            'hosts': [ip_address],
            'vars': {},
        },
        '_meta': {
            'hostvars': {
                ip_address: {
                    'ansible_ssh_user': 'ansible',
                }
            },
        },
        'ip': [ip_address]
    }


def find_ip():
    lines = subprocess.check_output(['arp', '-a']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        if re.search('a0:d7:95:1a:80:f8', line):
            ip = re.search(r"(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)", line)
            return ip.group(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
      "192.168.0.100": {
        "ansible_ssh_user": "ansible"
      }
    }
  },
  "all": {
    "hosts": [
      "192.168.0.100"
    ],
    "vars": {
      "ansible_connection": "local"
    }
  },
  "ip": [
    "192.168.0.100"
  ]
}
```

Example:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/dynamic/mydyn.py hosts.yml 

PLAY [Test wait] ****************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Debug] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.100] => {
    "ansible_host": "192.168.0.100"
}

TASK [Ping] *********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.100]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************
192.168.0.100              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```